# Why is Scheduled Reminders sending multiple emails but not creating an activity?

Tags: scheduled-reminders

I have a scheduled reminder set up to send a preset email 4 hours after a Completed Activity of a specific type. Today a user contacted me stating that they have received 8 emails within an hour of the preset email, however when looking at their record there are no activities showing that emails were sent.

I checked the Scheduled Jobs Log for the Send Scheduled Reminders job and found there were around 8 errors with the following error:

```
Entity: Job Action: send_reminder
Summary
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, Error message: API (ActionLog, get) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)
Details


Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}

Full message: 
Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, Error message: API (ActionLog, get) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)
```

It did have as it's last run a Success. There is still no activity recorded showing that any email was sent.

The Scheduled Reminder is set up to record an activity and is NOT set to repeat.

EDIT: Forgot to say I'm running Civi 4.6.4 and D7.

Comment: Hmm. I'm on 4.4.13 and I just did a grep on the civicrm directory. ActionLog exists as a BAO/DAO, and there are pre/post hooks on it, but I get the same error doing ActionLog.get in a drush command- in fact ActionLog isn't in the list of API entity types at all.

Comment: Something is seriously wrong with SR. It sends out an email every time cron runs and it's only supposed to do it once, 4 hours after the identified activity.

Comment: I upgraded to 4.6.5 and have tried to test it but it doesn't seem to be sending anything out now at all. Can anyone confirm whether something was broke with the API, scheduled jobs, and/or scheduled reminders?

Comment: Do you have CiviRules enabled.  See https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.civirules/issues/47

Comment: Ok,  so I'll disable CiviRules.