# Why are contacts getting multiple membership scheduled reminders?

Tags: civimail, scheduled-reminders

We saw this with a WordPress 4.4.2 CiviCRM 4.6.14 instance.

A reminder was sent every time cron was run.

This is not related to [Why is Scheduled Reminders sending multiple emails but not creating an activity?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4212/why-is-scheduled-reminders-sending-multiple-emails-but-not-creating-an-activity) an activity is created every time a reminder is sent.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug as [reported here](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18236) - when a membership end date is changed the system keeps sending scheduled reminders.

The issue is fixed in 4.7 but remains for 4.6